# Получить запись с вк

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api

Как получить 5 записей (текст, URL картинки) с сообщества ВКонтакте на JS или PHP

Не получается

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$wall_id="-95098766"; // Положительное число: пользователь. Отрицательное: группа.
$count="20"; // Количество записей, которое необходимо получить. Максимальное значение: 100. 
$api = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id={$wall_id}&count={$count}");
$wall = json_decode($api,true);
foreach ($wall['response'] as $item => $result) {
echo $result['text'].'<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: предоставьте пожалуйста ваш код, или вы хотите что-бы все написали за вас?

Comment: `file_get_contents` и документация к `wall.get` вам в помощь. А потом же конкретный вопрос спрашивайте

Comment: пробовала...не работает...сейчас код в пост добавлю

Comment: версию апи разве не надо в обязательном порядке добавлять к запросу?

Comment: Я не знаю. Впервые работаю с ВК. Если можете помочь исправить, то буду благодарна

Comment: @Анастасия, если по ответу какие-либо вопросы, дабы избежать дискуссий в комментариях, можете написать мне в [вк](https://vk.com/wnull)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказал @Eddir, у вас отсутствует обязательный параметр `access_token`, прочтите официальную [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/access_token) для чего он используется, как его можно и нужно получить.

В последнем своем [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895661/300000) тоже описывал запросы к VK API, там написал две функции `curl` и `vk`, для удобства отправки запросов, рекомендую ознакомиться с ними и использовать Вот код, который вам нужен с использованием вышеописанных функций:

```
$access_token = 'b037e92e5c403113449f2b3962279bgf341f5934d22';
$owner_id = '-95098766';
$count = 5;

$get = vk('wall.get', [
    'owner_id' => $owner_id,
    'v' => '5.85',
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'count' => $count
]);

// Если ответ response, то продолджаем
if (isset($get->response))
{   
    // Продолджаем работу, если записей больше 0
    if ($get->response->count > 0)
    {
        // Проходим циклом по полученным записям и записываем в массив c ключом 
        // [id] (id записи), а в зачение[] записывается подмассив с фото
        foreach ($get->response->items as $key => $value)
        {
            $new[$value->id] = [
                'text' => $value->text,
                'photo' => ($value->attachments[0]->photo) ? $value->attachments : 0
            ];
        }
    }

    // Выводим на экран наш собранный массив, и делаем с ним что угодно,
    // например далее получаем из его ссылки на изображения
    print_r($new);
}
```

**Важно**: в примере работа с объектами, а не с массивами, если вам нужно из объекта `$new` получить обычный массив `$new`, то `$new = (array) $new;` Полный код на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pE644wd4). Вот и все :)

**upd**: Совсем забыл, что вам нужен еще и текст, тогда вообще никаких проблем, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код не работает по причине того, что Вы не указали access_token в url запроса. Советую использовать хотя бы минимальные средства дебага, как var_dump. Сразу после file_get_contents пропишите `var_dump($api);` , чтобы знать наверняка, что вернул Вам в ответ ВК.

А для того, чтобы сделать алгоритм рабочим, изучите способы получения access_token по ссылке https://vk.com/dev/access_token . Проще всего получить токен сообщества или сервисный токен.