# Не работает отправка изображения API VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Делаю отправку фото и сообщения в группу через VK API
вроде и фото грузит, и ошибок не выдает, но в группе пусто, может кто сталкивался.

```
$group_id     = 'XXX';
$access_token = 'XXX';
$message      = 'Hello, world!';
$image        = 'img/corgiya18.jpg';

// Получение сервера vk для загрузки изображения.


$res = json_decode(file_get_contents(
  'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?group_id='
. $group_id . '&v=5.21&access_token=' . $access_token
));

if (!empty($res->response->upload_url)) {

    // Отправка изображения на сервер.

    $postparam=array("photo"=>"@".$image);
    $ch = curl_init($res->response->upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['photo' => new CurlFile($image)]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'));
    $res = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch); 



    if (!empty($res->server)) {
        // Сохранение фото в группе.

        $res = json_decode(file_get_contents(
            'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.saveWallPhoto?group_id=' . $group_id
            . '&v=5.21&server=' . $res->server . '&photo='
            . stripslashes($res->photo) . '&hash='
            . $res->hash . '&access_token=' . $access_token

        ));


        if (!empty($res->response[0]->id)) {
            // Отправляем сообщение.
            $params = array(
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'owner_id'     => '-' . $group_id, 
                'from_group'   => '1', 
                'message'      => $message,
                'attachments'  => $res->response[0]->id
            );

            file_get_contents(
                'https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?' . http_build_query($params)
            );
        }else{echo "error";}
    }else{echo "error1";}
}
?>
```

Comment: Вы передаете  в `'attachments'`  => `$res->response[0]->id`, но это только `id`, структура этого параметра должна быть следующей: `photo{id_user с токена которого вы загружаете фото}_{тут уже id фотографии}`. Еще, stripslashes необязательно использовать, также `@` перед `$image` не нужно делать, т.к. вы используете `new CURLFile`.

Comment: Я же через массив params все это передаю, или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: если вам помог ответ, и решил вашу проблему, то нажмите зеленую галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы принять его. Если же не помог, напишите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях описал основные ваши проблемы, но еще хотелось бы отметить, чтобы вы не забывали следить за последней версией API, это обязательный параметр.

Как бы сделал подобную реализацию я. Я бы написал 2 функции `curl`и `vk` (функция, с помощью которой делали запросы к API VK передавая *название метода* и *нужные параметры*), чтобы было удобнее, и не путаться каждый раз в запросах, вот самый простой пример использования:

```
function vk($method, $params)
{
    return json_decode(curl('https://api.vk.com/method/'.$method, $params));
}

function curl($url, $params = false)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if (isset($params))
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    }

    $upd = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $upd;
}
```

Берем данные, которые нам нужны: токен, id группы, путь к фотографии, и сообщение:

```
$group_id     = '162947920';
$access_token = '1fdf6eec18dba97f3ccf72c03fc8e29155e032044ed763f68a3e8216';
$message      = 'Hello, world!';
$image        = 'img/corgiya18.jpg';
```

Итак, заметил, что вы любите декодировать json и получать его в виде объекта, ну что же, имея эти две функции можно набросать совсем несложный код:

```
$url = vk('photos.getWallUploadServer', [
    'group_id' => $group_id,
    'v' => '5.85',
    'access_token' => $access_token
])->response->upload_url; // Обращаемся сразу к <response[upload_url]>

if (isset($url))
{
    $upload = json_decode(curl($url, ['photo' => new CURLFile($image)]));

    if (isset($upload->server))
    {
        $save = vk('photos.saveWallPhoto', [
            'group_id' => $group_id,
            'server' => $upload->server,
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'hash' => $upload->hash,
            'photo' => $upload->photo,
            'v' => '5.85'
        ])->response[0]; // Обращаемся сразу к <response[0]>

        if (isset($save))
        {
            $post = vk('wall.post', [
                'owner_id' => '-'.$group_id,
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'from_group' => 1,
                'message' => $message,
                'attachments' => 'photo'.$save->owner_id.'_'.$save->id,
                'v' => '5.85'
            ]);

            print_r($post);
        }
    }
}
```

Полный код на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0JpwnCK0). Рекомендую ознакомиться с [документацией](https://vk.com/dev/methods) каждого метода :)

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо)

Comment: @илья, как я уже говорил, если помог ответ, нажмите зелёную Галочку рядом с ним, чтобы его принять, если это не сложно)

Comment: а не подскажете, как это переделать на отправку документа?

Comment: @илья, а в чем собственно проблема?