# Загрузить фотографию по url в альбом сообщества (vk api)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Подскажите, что не так делаю? Вот код:

```
class Model_Vk {

    private $access_token;
    private $url = "https://api.vk.com/method/";

    /**
     * Конструктор
     */
    public function __construct($access_token) {

        $this->access_token = $access_token;
    }

    /**
     * Делает запрос к Api VK
     * @param $method
     * @param $params
     */
    public function method($method, $params = null) {

        $p = "";
        if( $params && is_array($params) ) {
            foreach($params as $key => $param) {
                $p .= ($p == "" ? "" : "&") . $key . "=" . urlencode($param);
            }
        }
        $response = file_get_contents($this->url . $method . "?" . ($p ? $p . "&" : "") . "v=" . VK_API_VERSION ."&". "access_token=" . $this->access_token);

        if( $response ) {
            return json_decode($response);
        }
        return false;
    }

  public function uploadImage($file, $group_id = null, $album_id = null) {

    $params = array();
    if( $group_id ) {
      $params['group_id'] = $group_id;
    }
    if( $album_id ) {
      $params['album_id'] = $album_id;
    }

    //Получаем сервер для загрузки изображения
    $response = $this->method("photos.getUploadServer", $params);


    if( isset($response) == false ) {
      print_r($response);
      exit;
    }


    $server = $response->response->upload_url;
    // file_put_contents('img.jpg', file_get_contents($file));
    // $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/img.jpg';
    $postparam=array("file1"=>"@".$file);
    //$postparam = new CURLFile($file);
    print_r($postparam);
    echo '<br>';
    //Отправляем файл на сервер
    $ch = curl_init($server);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postparam);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'));
    $json = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($json);
    echo '<br>';


    //Сохраняем файл в альбом
    $photo = $this->method("photos.save", array(
      "server" => $json->server,
      "photos_list" => $json->photos_list,
      "album_id" => $album_id,
      "hash" => $json->hash,
      "gid" => $group_id
    ));
    print_r($photo);
    echo '<br>';
    if( isset($photo->response[0]->id) ) {
      return $photo->response[0]->id;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

До того как пытаюсь передать url картинки на сервер происходит нормально (получаю токен, адрес сервера), но после передачи постом картинки на адрес сервера возвращает пустой массив `photos_list`, url картинки вида `https://cdn.thesolesupplier.co.uk/2017/09/MITA-x-ASICS-GT-II-Squirrel-Brown-05.png`, в чем проблема?

Comment: `file1"=>"@".$file`, заменяйте на `new CURLFile($file)`, вот тут недавно отвечал на [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895661/300000), обязательно посмотрите, да, и еще, необязательно передавать заголовки, к картинке желательно указывать полный путь.

Comment: upd. На сервер нужно передавать путь к файлу, который уже находится на вашем сервере, а не ссылку на фото.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях вам указал основные ваши проблемы с реализацией, для того, чтобы загрузить фотографию на сервер VK, фотография должна быть уже на вашем сервере, и, для дальнейшей загрузки, вы должны указать полный путь к этой фотографии. Сначала сохраняете фото на своем сервере, потом загружаете уже в VK.

Касаемо вашей модели, теория хорошая, но реализация ужасная. По недавно оставленному моему [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/895661/300000) касаемо загрузки фотографий на сервер ВК, можно набросать несложный класс:

```
class Model_VK
{
    public $access_token, $v;
    const API = 'https://api.vk.com/method/';

    public function __construct($access_token, $v)
    {
        $this->access_token = $access_token;
        $this->v = $v;
    }

    public function uploadImage($file, $group_id = null, $album_id = null)
    {
        list($params['group_id'], $params['album_id']) = [$group_id, $album_id];

        $upl = $this->vk('photos.getUploadServer', $params)->response->upload_url;

        if (isset($upl))
        {
            $upload = json_decode($this->curl($upl, ['file1' => new CURLFile($file)]));

            if (isset($upload->server))
            {
                $photo = $this->vk('photos.save', [
                      'server' => $upload->server,
                      'photos_list' => $upload->photos_list,
                      'album_id' => $album_id,
                      'hash' => $upload->hash,
                      'group_id' => $group_id
                ]);

                print_r($photo);
            }
        }
    }

    public function vk($method, $params)
    {
        list($params['access_token'], $params['v']) = [$this->access_token, $this->v];

        return json_decode($this->curl(self::API . $method, $params));
    }

    public function curl($url, $params = false)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        if (isset($params))
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        }

        $upd = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $upd;
    }
}
```

Имея это, создаем экземпляр класса и обращаемся к функции `uploadImage`:

```
$new = new Model_VK('token_user', '5.85');
$new->uploadImage(__DIR__.'/photo.jpg', 158853183, 251951515);
```

После загрузки фотографии в альбом, на экран будет выведен результат. Вот и все :)

Comment: действительно, не подумал что файл должен быть на сервере (ужасная документация по api). Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ!

Comment: @Денис, не за что :)