# Как загрузить фотку на сервер Вк photos пустой

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, api

Помогите загрузить фотки, много искал, не нашёл.Mac os путь с самой системы.Когда пыютась проложить путь с '@' пишет просто null. А так параметр photos пустой.
Вот код 
        $link = $request->img;

```
    $uploaddir = 'img/';
    $file_name = basename($link);
    file_put_contents('img'.$file_name, file_get_contents($request->img));

    $GET_getWallUploadServer = [
        'group_id' => $group_id,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => 5.101,
    ];
    $resukt_url_dp = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer?'.http_build_query($GET_getWallUploadServer)), TRUE);
    //Загружаем фото КУРЛом, отправляя ПОСТ на полученю ссылку

    $photourl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/";

    $curl_file = new CURLFile($photourl,'image/jpeg','test_name.jpg');

    $ch= curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $resukt_url_dp['response']['upload_url'],
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array("photo" => $curl_file)
    ));
    $img_attach = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
    dd($img_attach);
```

Вот выхлоп:

```
array:3 [▼
  "server" => 855336
  "photo" => "[]"
  "hash" => "e5974317bd733b9b927ec426528c9974"
]
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает отправка изображения API VK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/895623/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-api-vk)

Comment: Нет, именно ответ, когда пытаюсь загрузить на сервер вк, там должен быть id в параметре photos, но его нет

Comment: Почему вы в CURLFile передаёте путь к папке, а не к файлу? Скорее всего именно в этом и ошибка